# How to create a pdf from a simple utf8 text file using pandoc?

Tags: linux, pdf, text, utf-8, pandoc

I created a pdf using pandoc in linux, but the pdf can not be opened by Adobe Reader giving the following msg.

> Adobe Reader could not open 'utf8text.pdf' because it is either not a supported file ype or because the file has been damaged(for example, it was sent as an email attachment and wasn't correctly decoded).

I use the following command to create the pdf from text file.

> pandoc utf8text.txt -o utf8text.pdf

What am I doing wrong?

Thank you.

Comment: Sanity check: does your PDF work *without* the UTF8-encoded characters?

Comment: Do you have the necessary Latex packages installed as described here (http://johnmacfarlane.net/pandoc/demo/example19/Creating-a-PDF.html)?

Comment: Thank you for the reply. Jongware, the plain text pdf without UTF-8 created by pandoc can not be opened by Reader, giving the same error.    Axel Kemper, how do you install latex and which latex?  I use fedora13. Thank you.

Comment: I see that texlive-latex.i686 texlive-texmf-errata-latex.noarch texlive-texmf-latex.noarch are installed already.